# Can't run with Face Recognition imported in Python App

Tags: python, face-recognition, dlib

When I try to run app.py with Face Recognition imported in Python I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 10, in <module>
    import face_recognition as fr
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/face_recognition/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .api import load_image_file, face_locations, batch_face_locations, face_landmarks, face_encodings, compare_faces, face_distance
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/face_recognition/api.py", line 4, in <module>
    import dlib
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dlib/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from _dlib_pybind11 import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_dlib_pybind11.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_png_do_expand_palette_rgb8_neon'
```

The app will run with the import line commented out. I have CMake, dlib and pip installed. Also trie uninstalling and installing again.

Comment: try using venv and install face_recognition in a virtual environment to see if it works in an isolated environment. Also, if you have access to another computer, try on another computer. If it works on any of those tests, then we would probably need to see your code to see why it could be failing.

Comment: @SOUser418 Thanks for the reply. I've installed it on a venv within my project along with testing it on another new project with a venv attached. I haven't tried it yet on another computer as I only have another Mac M1 (which is what I'm currently using).